# Visual force Page throwing error on New record

Tags: apex, visualforce, master-detail

I have a related list on a master record, when I clicked NEW on the child record it is suppose to bring the visual force page(which by the way works fine for edit), but instead it gave the error
**Attempt to de-reference a null object** 
I'm using URL for the NEW button and appending id of the parent record also,so my URL looks like
`/apex/Pg_Revenue?PA__c=a04e0000004ncfx`
where `Pg_Revenue` is the visual force page and `PA__c` is linked field of child record and `a04e0000004ncfx` is the id of master record.
I must be making some silly mistake.

### **here is the Pg_REvenue page**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Revenue__c" extensions="RevenueExt" >
<apex:messages />
    <apex:sectionheader title="{!$ObjectType.Revenue__c.label} Edit" subtitle="{!IF(ISNULL(Revenue__c.Name), 'New Revenue',Revenue__c.Name)}"/>
    <apex:form >
  <apex:pageblock mode="edit" title="{!$ObjectType.Revenue__c.label} Edit">
            <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!SaveAndReturn}"/>
                <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
                      <apex:outputpanel >
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="true" columns="2">
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Revenue__c.Name}" required="true"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Revenue__c.Amount__c}" required="true"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Revenue__c.Revenue_Interval__c}" required="true"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Revenue__c.Number_of_Milestones__c}" required="true"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Revenue__c.Revenue_Start_Date__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Revenue__c.COGS__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Revenue__c.GM__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:outputfield value="{!Revenue__c.PA__c}" />
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Revenue__c.Product_Type__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!Revenue__c.Product_sub_Type__c}" required="false"/>
                    <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

---

### **Here is Controller**

```
public with sharing class RevenueExt
{
private final List<Revenue__c> revs=new List<Revenue__c>();
private Integer milestone;
private final Revenue__c Currentrev;
private Integer f =0;
private ApexPages.standardController controller  {get; set;}
private date newDate;

public RevenueExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
   this.controller = controller;
  currentrev = (Revenue__c)controller.getRecord();
  milestone = (currentrev.Number_of_Milestones__c).intValue();
}
public PageReference Cancel()
{
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+currentrev.PA__c);
            pr.setRedirect(true);
            return(pr); }

public PageReference saveAndReturn()
{
    PageReference pr =  controller.cancel();
    for (Integer x=0;x<milestone;x++){
    if (currentrev.Revenue_Interval__c == 'Monthly')  {
        newDate = (currentrev.Revenue_Start_Date__c).AddMonths(x);
    }
    if (currentrev.Revenue_Interval__c == 'Yearly')  {
        newDate = (currentrev.Revenue_Start_Date__c).AddYears(x);
    }
    if (currentrev.Revenue_Interval__c == 'Quarterly')  {
        integer y = x*3;
        newDate = (currentrev.Revenue_Start_Date__c).AddMonths(y);
    }
    if(currentrev.Revenue_Interval__c == 'Non Recurring'){
         newDate = (currentrev.Revenue_Start_Date__c);
    }

       revs.add(new Revenue__c(PA__c = currentrev.PA__c,
                              name = currentrev.name,
                              Number_of_Milestones__c = 1,
                              COGS__c = currentrev.COGS__c,
                              GM__c = currentrev.GM__c,
                              Product_Type__c = currentrev.Product_Type__c,
                              Product_sub_Type__c = currentrev.Product_sub_Type__c,
                              Amount__c = currentrev.Amount__c,

                              Revenue_Start_Date__c = newDate ));
                                 // controller.save();
   }
   insert revs;
    return (pr);
}
}
```

---

Comment: Post the code for your controller on the `Pg_Revenue` Page.

Comment: hi Adrian, I have added code

Comment: Post your code for the extension "RevenueExt".

Comment: AAU , I have added code.

Comment: only VF page is posted, we need to see the controller code - which is where the null reference is occurring

Comment: crop1645 I have just added code for controller, which insert multiple records based on interval selected.